# Android market logs: mysterious NullPointerExceptions in web views

Tags: android, webview, crash, admob, google-play

I have lots of null pointer exceptions lately in my logs from the market. I am using webviews only in the ad networks I am using, some of which are: AdMob, InMobi, etc.

I saw some problems with AdMob on this. Do you know if admob is the problem, and if there are any workarounds for that?

I am closing crashes by extending some views and catching the exceptions there, but I know there will be quite nasty side effects. And some of the methods I cannot override...

Any help appreciated!!!
Dan

here are few examples:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.webkit.WebView.addAccessibilityApisToJavaScript(WebView.java:1491)
>   at android.webkit.WebView.onAttachedToWindow(WebView.java:6834)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:8195)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1923)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1928)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1928)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1928)
>   ...
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.webkit.WebView.requestFocus(WebView.java:9262)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1079)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1035)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1079)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1035)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1079)

Comment: These both look like Android WebView crashes that perhaps the ad network SDKs are exposing.  I have lots of experience with AdMob, and I've seen some instances of the second crash with those who use AdMob, but I've never seen the first.  Perhaps one of your other ad networks is exposing that webview crash.